# Does reviewing yield reputation points?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I know the answer to this is somewhere, but I can't find it.

Can you gain reputation points by completing the reviewing activities, and if so for which activities.

Is there a document somewhere that lists everything that yields points?

Comment: No, it doesn't; reputation earns you privileges, to help moderate the site. Helping to moderate the site does not then earn you reputation again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wishful thinking I guess. It wouldn't hurt to off +1 point just to encourage people to help moderate.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: We want people to help moderate because they genuinely care about the quality of the site, or because they understand that a quality site attracts more opportunities to gain reputation in the long run. Awarding reputation for moderating would attract people to the task for the wrong reasons, which would hurt quality. We already see this with just badges in the review queues.

Comment: @Martijn True, but who should really get the advanced moderation privileges (earned from reputation)?  It should be given to those who are helping to moderate the site.  It could be given to those who answer and ask questions too, but it seems more rational to give the tools to people who are using the tools that they already have to the best of their ability.

Comment: @Anonymous: currently we give it to those that are experienced in using the site, as measured by their reputation. It has worked out quite well, mostly.

Comment: @Martijn But, what I'm saying is that when a low quality question shows up, a person has two options: answer or downvote/close/flag.  Are those who choose to answer really more qualified to have better tools to deal with low quality questions?

Comment: That's a different issue; that's one of the reasons gold tag badge holders can close a question with just one vote, to head off quick answers on often-repeated dupes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean reputation.

And no, reviews don't earn you reputation.

Accepting an answer by someone other than you on your question, getting upvotes on your question or answer, having your suggested edits accepted, getting an answer accepted, winning a bounty and the association bonus are the ways to gain reputation in the system.

The gory details about reputation can be found at:

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)